# jQuery focus event goes into infinite recursion

Tags: jquery

I tried a simple example ([FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3p7cdynt/)). Similar to this example, I have some code that needs to be executed when a tab/window is focused(but once).

```
jQuery(window).focus(function(){
  alert();
});
```

Why the focus event goes with infinite recursion. When I tried in firefox, it kept on showing alerts until firefox gave me a **"too much recursion"** error and broke out of the recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code is saying every time the page is focused show an alert which will itself cause the page to focus again.

To clarify the focus function is actually creating an event handler on the entire window which will be called when the window is focused, it is not telling the browser to focus on the window.

So focus -> alert -> focus -> alert -> focus ........ to the infinity === "too much recursion"

Comment: [gabriel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2330575/gabriel) Thanks for answering. Can accept the answer in 7 mins.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
var customFunction = function (event) {

    window.removeEventListener('focus',customFunction, false );
    alert("hi");
};
window.addEventListener("focus", customFunction, false);
```